# Как убрать event.target с определенного элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я создал окружность `<div class="custom-cursor__circle"></div>` со стилями:

```css
.custom-cursor__circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

и привязал ее к движению мыши:

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.custom-cursor__circle');

function onMouseMove(e) {
    circle.style.left = e.pageX - 10 + 'px';
    circle.style.top = e.pageY - 10 + 'px';
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
```

Но теперь любой обработчик событий, который я хочу запустить на других элементах, срабатывает на эту окружность. Т.е. в любом месте экрана event.target будет равен моей окружности. Как я могу это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно было добавить `pointer-events: none;` к окружности.